# iOS -> Can Non-Consumable In app purchases actually contains code?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

Can my non-consumable in app purchase package actually contain new code? code that will add or alter or extend features? Or the in app purchase is merely a record that will enable me to detect if the current user purchased something?

Answer (score 0):

They have an id and you will do anything according to that id. So whenever a user buys a non-consumable with the id of let's say "x", you extend a feature accordingly. Also you need to add "restore purchases" option exactly for that matter. To re-enable those features.

Comment: well, thanks for the input, but you didn't actually answer the question...

Comment: It is just a record. You will have to implement the code to enable/extend those features.